# How to run exe file on CruiseControl

Tags: c++, cruisecontrol

I've been looking through CruiseControl documentation and I found tag  and 
for running scripts. But when I am trying to run  exe-file from that tags  it does not work as well as it described in documantation.

I also tried to put call of the exe in batch file and execute it from CruiseControl but also did not work as I expected. So how can I run exe-file from CC? I also need to be able to include output of this file work in my email notification is it possible at all?
E.g. I have file UnitTests.exe which prints something like this:

```
Unit tests are passed.
47 Tests was successful
```

How can I do this? Or how can I at least get an returning code from that executable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the exec in ant.
In cruisecontrol:

```
    <schedule>
        <ant anthome="/usr/apache-ant-1.8.2" buildfile="/usr/ant-build-files/my-ant-build-file.build" target="do-task" uselogger="true">
        </ant>
    </schedule>
```

In /usr/ant-build-files/my-ant-build-file.build
...

```
    <target name="do-task">             
        <exec executable="/<path to dir containing exe>/UnitTests.exe" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="<args to UnitTests.exe>"/>
    </exec>
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But what did you mean by this line <target>doit</target>. What shall I write instead of doit to run file UnitTests.exe ?

Comment: Can you please post full Nant config file to run UnitTests.exe? I will be very thankful.

Comment: Are you talking about cruiseControl or cruisecontrol .net? I am interested only in usual cruiseControl. Can you pls post more specific nant config file description?

Comment: I edited my original post to use regular Java Cruisecontrol and Ant.

Answer (score 0):

There is option to execute .bat or .exe files using the following tag.

```
  <exec executable="c:/something.exe" />
```

You can place the above line in any target of the xml files that your build script is going to call.

```
<target name="target-to-call-an-exe">
      <exec executable="c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe" />
</target>
```

Hope this helps, Thanks.